# Rails - AJAX to for new/create action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a timeline with events partials on it so that you can CRUD events directly on the timeline page. I've got it working so that you can delete an event, and the delete partial refreshes along with the timeline, without the page refreshing.

But I can't get it working for a new event, or to edit one. Please can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong? Thanks!

I've put the code for a new event here, as I'm sure between the new and delete, I can work out how to sort the editing.

timelines/show:

```
 <div id="show-timeline">
   <%= render :partial => "show_timeline" %>
 </div>

    <div id="my-timeline-box">
        <%= render :partial => "my_timeline" %>
    </div>

<div id="new-event">
    <%= render :partial => "new_event", :locals => { :event => Event.new(:timeline_id=>@timeline.id) }, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

timelines/_new_event.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(event) do |f| %>
  <% if event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%=f.hidden_field 'timeline_id', :value => current_user.timeline.id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :start_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1800 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :headline, :size => 50 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :event_description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :text, :size => "47x4" %>
  </div>
  <%= check_box_tag "blockCheck", :value => "1", :checked => false %>
  <div class="field" id="media_box">
    <%= f.label :media %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Please paste a URL here</span><br />
    <%= f.text_field :media, :size => 50 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :media_description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :caption, :size => "47x3" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Create Event', :class => "btn btn-success"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

events/create.js.erb:

```
$('#new-event').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/new_event", :locals => { :event => Event.new(:timeline_id=>@timeline.id) } ) %>');
$('.notice').html("<p>Event was successfully created.</p>");
$('.notice').show(300);
$('#my-timeline-box').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/my_timeline" ) %>');
$('#show-timeline').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/show_timeline" ) %>');
```

events controller:

```
def new
    @event = Event.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
      format.js
    end
  end

def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event.timeline, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you can't get it working? Are you getting an error in Rails or in the JavaScript? Have you tried debugging to make sure the correct values are being passed from the form to the controller?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that instead of the partials refreshing like I want them to, the page still redirects to timelines/1 - i.e. the page refreshes instead.

Comment: I'm guessing this means that it is possibly an issue with the code in the controller?

Comment: Is this making an ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

The `:remote => true` option on `render :partial` in the timelines/show view is not required.

Instead the `form_for` in `_new_event.html.erb` should have the options :remote (this makes the form submit via ajax) and :format (this requests the response be in JavaScript), e.g.:

```
<%= form_for event, :remote => true, :format => :js do |f| %>
```